# How can I add headers and indent checkboxes when using checkboxGroupInput in Shiny?

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I want to add headers to my checkboxes and indent the checkboxes, so they look like this:

```
Uppercase
  [] A
  [] B
  [] C
Lowercase
  [] a
  [] b
  [] c
```

Here is my code

```
letters <- c("A","B","C","a","b","c")
library("shiny")
server <-function(input, output) {
    output$value <- renderPrint({ input$checkGroup })
}

ui <-fluidPage(
         checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", 
                            label = h3("my letters"), 
                            choices = letters,
         fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))
)

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To indent the checkboxes you can set their left margin style.

To have 2 groups you can simply split your data and make 2 `checkboxGroupInput`s:

```
lletters <- c("a","b","c")
uletters <- c("A","B","C")
library("shiny")
server <-function(input, output) {
  checkGroup <- reactive(c(input$checkGroupL,input$checkGroupU))
  output$value <- renderPrint(checkGroup())
}

ui <-fluidPage( 
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".checkbox {margin-left:15px}"))),
  checkboxGroupInput("checkGroupL",
                     label = h3("Lower case"), 
                     choices = lletters),
  checkboxGroupInput("checkGroupU", 
                     label = h3("Upper case"), 
                     choices = uletters),
  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value"))))

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

[image]