# Pass list of values to Shiny checkbox

Tags: r, shiny

Suppose you have a list of values:

```
my_choices<-list("foo"=c("a", "b", "c"), "bar"=c("1", "2", "3"))

> my_choices
$foo
[1] "a" "b" "c"
$bar
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```

Is it possible to pass this list to a Shiny Checkbox such that `foo` and `bar` become group headings while a, b, c and 1, 2, 3 become selections under those headings? [This functionality exists for `selectInput`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/selectInput.html) but I was wondering if similar functionality exists for checkboxes.

For technical reasons within the app I am working, I cannot use two different UI objects (e.g. a checkbox element for `foo` and another for `bar`, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43507499/how-can-i-add-headers-and-indent-checkboxes-when-using-checkboxgroupinput-in-shi).) I require headings within a single UI element. The below MRE Shiny app only shows selections for the headings (`foo` and `bar`; not the values under those headings.)

```
library(shiny)


my_choices<-list("foo"=c("a", "b", "c"), 
                    "bar"=c("1", "2", "3"))

ui <- fluidPage(

   checkboxGroupInput("variable", 
                      "Variables to show:",
                      my_choices)
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create list of `checkboxGroupInput` dynamically using `Map`.

```
library(shiny)

my_choices<-list("foo"=c("a", "b", "c"), 
                 "bar"=c("1", "2", "3"))

ui <- fluidPage(
 uiOutput('checkbox')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$checkbox <- renderUI({
    Map(function(x, y) checkboxGroupInput(y,y, x), my_choices, names(my_choices))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

`Map` is similar to a loop which works on two arguments in parallel i.e `my_choices` and `names(my_choices)`. For every element in `my_choices` it creates a `checkboxGroupInput` whose `inputId` and `label` is the corresponding name and `choices` are the values in that list.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Are you able to provide a little explanation as to how `Map` is working in this particular example?

Comment: Edited the answer to include some explanation.

Comment: Is it possible to not create two `checkboxGroupInput` objects using `Map`? I don't need to create two checkbox outputs, I just need to nest the headings.

Comment: Can you ask that as a new question?

Comment: Of couse. For those two may stumble across this in the future, here's a link to the new qyestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67121474/group-headings-for-groupcheckboxinput