# Group headings for groupCheckboxInput

Tags: r, shiny

In `shinywidgets::pickerInput` you can pass a named list of data (here, `nms`) to `pickerInput` to create headings and choices from the list.

For example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
  
nms = list('Consumers' = c('a', 'b'), 
             'Firms' = c('c', 'd'))
  
ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "somevalue",
    label = "A label",
    choices = nms,
    selected = 'a',
    multiple=T
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  )
  
server <- function(input, output) {
   output$value <- renderPrint(input$somevalue)
}
  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I wish to replicate this heading/choices functionality using `shinyWidgets::awesomeCheckboxGroup`. Previously I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66917706/pass-list-of-values-to-shiny-checkbox/) seeking an answer and was advised that `Map` could do this. However, `Map` creates *two* input objects; I do not require this. The user's choices all need to be fed into a single input object.
Is it possible to create headings in `awesomeCheckboxGroup` while retaining a single input object?

Comment: I couldn't find an example where `awesomeCheckboxGroup` works with a named list. Do you have any such example?

Comment: I'm afraid not. It's a curious omission given that `pickerInput` and `awesomeCheckboxGroup` are functions within the same package. Both are essentially doing the same thing, it's just the UI that's different. I may have to roll my sleeves up and compare the source code between the two methods to see whether it can be hacked.

Comment: You can simply do two widgets `A` and `B` and use a reactive variable `reactive(c(input$A, input$B))`.

Comment: In my particular use case, I don't think concatting lists into a single reactive variable is a workable solution. I have some downstream code which only lets users select 3 or less checkboxes; when they select a 4th, it deselects their 3rd choice. To do this I'm leveraging `updateAwesomeCheckboxGroup` to update the UI dynamically. It starts getting difficult to track what `awesomeCheckboxGroup` the check deselection should be attributed to if I concat many checkbox groups. This is why I need a single `checkboxInput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the source code and modified `awesomeCheckboxGroup` and the underlying function `generateAwesomeOptions` to make it work. Now we can use named lists, which will create sub labels, and unnamed vectors, which will produce the normal checkboxes. We could still optimize the code a bit, and I am also not sure how the labels should look like. But basically you can give them a special class attribute and then use CSS to change the appearance of the labels.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

generateAwesomeOptions2 <- function (inputId, choices, selected, inline, status, flag = FALSE) {

  # if input is a list, flag will be set to `TRUE` by the calling function
  if (flag) {

  options <-  mapply(choices, names(choices), FUN = function(lchoices, lname) {

    lchoices <- shinyWidgets:::choicesWithNames(lchoices)

    tags$div(
      tags$label(lname, style = "margin-bottom: 10px;"),

    mapply(lchoices, names(lchoices), FUN = function(value, name) {

    inputTag <- tags$input(type = "checkbox", name = inputId,
                           value = value, id = paste0(inputId, value))
    if (value %in% selected)
      inputTag$attribs$checked <- "checked"
    if (inline) {
      tags$div(class = paste0("awesome-checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-",
                              status), inputTag, tags$label(name, `for` = paste0(inputId,
                                                                                 value)))
    }
    # flag is not set `TRUE` this will create the normal checkboxes
    else {
      tags$div(class = paste0("awesome-checkbox checkbox-",
                              status), inputTag, tags$label(name, `for` = paste0(inputId,
                                                                                 value)))
    }
  }, SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  )

  }, SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)} else {

    options <- mapply(choices, names(choices), FUN = function(value,
                                                              name) {
      inputTag <- tags$input(type = "checkbox", name = inputId,
                             value = value, id = paste0(inputId, value))
      if (value %in% selected)
        inputTag$attribs$checked <- "checked"
      if (inline) {
        tags$div(class = paste0("awesome-checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-",
                                status), inputTag, tags$label(name, `for` = paste0(inputId,
                                                                                   value)))
      }
      else {
        tags$div(class = paste0("awesome-checkbox checkbox-",
                                status), inputTag, tags$label(name, `for` = paste0(inputId,
                                                                                   value)))
      }
    }, SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)


    }

  tags$div(class = "shiny-options-group", options)


}

awesomeCheckboxGroup2 <- function (inputId, label, choices, selected = NULL, inline = FALSE,
                                   status = "primary", width = NULL) {
  if(!is.list(choices)) {

  choices <- shinyWidgets:::choicesWithNames(choices)
  selected <- shiny::restoreInput(id = inputId, default = selected)
  if (!is.null(selected))
    selected <- shinyWidgets:::validateSelected(selected, choices, inputId)
  options <- generateAwesomeOptions2(inputId, choices, selected,
                                     inline, status = status)

  } else {
    choices2 <- unlist(unname(choices))
    choices2 <- shinyWidgets:::choicesWithNames(choices2)
    selected <- shiny::restoreInput(id = inputId, default = selected)

    if (!is.null(selected))
      selected <- shinyWidgets:::validateSelected(selected, choices2, inputId)
    options <- generateAwesomeOptions2(inputId, choices, selected,
                                       inline, status = status, flag = TRUE)
  }

  divClass <- "form-group shiny-input-container shiny-input-checkboxgroup awesome-bootstrap-checkbox"
  if (inline)
    divClass <- paste(divClass, "shiny-input-container-inline")
  awesomeTag <- tags$div(id = inputId, style = if (!is.null(width))
    paste0("width: ", validateCssUnit(width), ";"), class = divClass,
    tags$label(label, `for` = inputId, style = "margin-bottom: 10px;"),
    options)
  shinyWidgets:::attachShinyWidgetsDep(awesomeTag, "awesome")
}


nms = list('Consumers' = c('a', 'b'),
           'Firms' = c('c', 'd'))

nms1 = c("Test", "Test2")

ui <- fluidPage(
  awesomeCheckboxGroup2(
    inputId = "somevalue",
    label = "Make a choice:",
    choices = nms
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderPrint(input$somevalue)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks very much for taking the time to look into this. I suspect the package authors would be interested in a PR: https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/issues/383